# java.lang.System error in Console()

Tags: java

```
public class ABC{
    public static void main(string... as)
    {
        char i;
        i = System.console().readLine("Hi ");
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I am getting error in this code.

The error is :-
console() not found in java.lang.System.

and if i am putting some constant then the code is properly working.

Please Help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of the Java sdk are you using? If it's not 1.6, then that's the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `java.util.Scanner` or InputStreamReader.

```
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   sc.nextLine();
```

or

```
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   br.readLine()
```

Comment: Have you checked the API before answering? Consider deleting this answer.

Comment: Ok its in Java.IO package. so is that package to be imported first then only it run?

Answer (score 5):

Use [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class that is available.

Below is the example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //
        // Read string input for username
        //
        System.out.print("Username: ");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();

        //
        // Read string input for password
        //
        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        //
        // Read an integer input for another challenge
        //
        System.out.print("What is 2 + 2: ");
        int result = scanner.nextInt();

        if (username.equals("admin") 
                && password.equals("secret") && result == 4) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Java Application");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid username or password, " +
                    "access denied!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a Console available (it isn't available in all environments), so don't use it. Instead why not use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object? For more on this, please check out the [Scanner Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

Comment: Thanks and Is Scanner available in all environment ?

Comment: @Vinit: yes, it is. Initialize it by passing `System.in` in its constructor. Edit: as @Fahim shows.