# Runtime error of Console() 

Tags: java, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

I have installed the JDK version 1.6 now the code is compiled but throws a run-time error

```
class Console1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.console().readLine("this is how we give he input to the string");
        System.out.println("this is what we want to print:0)");
    }
}
```

### Output

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Console
```

Comment: Your class is named Console1, not Console.

Comment: How do you run the code? From the command line? What command have you typed?

Comment: instead of changing class name its getting the same error

Comment: @buc eclipse , textpad and also by command line

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running with a different version of Java. Add this as the first line of code to your "application". It will show the java version which is used to run the application.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this is related to your other thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665343/java-lang-system-error-in-console).

System.console() returns the Console object, which was added in JDK 1.6, you say you have installed jdk 1.6, so one can only assume that your versions of java you are using to compile and run your code are different.

Can you please tell me what you are using to compile the code, and how you are running the code?

In future, please use the same thread you initially posted, it's much easier for people to trace.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of console you can use...

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = bufferRead.readLine();
```

see [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/)